# rm on cygwin, cannot unlink not owner

Tags: unix, cygwin

I need to delete all files/dirs named .svn using rm on cgywin

```
drwxr-xr-x    6      4096 Oct 26 15:33 .svn

$ rm -d .svn
rm: cannot unlink `.svn': Not owner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the adminsitrator on your machine, ownership is a concept that shouldn't concern you much.

Do `chmod u+w .svn`, then try your remove again.

Comment: not sure that'll work on cygwin.  may need `cacls` (if administrator) to get permissions on the file.

Comment: @~quack.  Thanks - You may be right - I think there is a dependency with the CYGWIN environment variable (http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) I may have forgotten about.

Comment: The CYGWIN variable needs to include a setting for ntea (NT Extended Attributes). This should be done in the file cygnus.bat. Add the following line in the file:  `export CYGWIN=ntea`

Comment: good find, but actually i think you want `ntsec` not `ntea` (same link, further down the page), to get real permissions instead of faked.  more here: http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html ...

Answer (score 3):

super-user (root) is the only account able to use `rm -d` flag

---

From the rm man page

```
-d, --directory

      unlink FILE, even if it is  a  non-empty  directory  (super-user
      only; this works only if your system supports ‘unlink’ for 
          nonempty directories)
```

You will need to `su root` or something similar before using `rm -d`

Have you tried `rm -rf /full/path/to/dir` or (if empty) `rmdir /full/path/to/dir` ?

Comment: +1 for ````rm -rf````.