# rm on MINGW32, cannot unlink not owner

Tags: rm, mingw

Similar to [rm on cygwin, cannot unlink not owner](https://superuser.com/questions/61197/rm-on-cygwin-cannot-unlink-not-owner), but for MINGW32.  I tried chmod u+w path but this did not help.

```
user@computer /d
$ rm dir -d
rm: cannot unlink `dir': Not owner

user@computer /d
$ chmod u+w dir

user@computer /d
$ rm dir -d
rm: cannot unlink `dir': Not owner
```

Answer (score 3):

super-user (root) is the only account able to use `rm -d` flag

---

From the rm man page

```
-d, --directory

      unlink FILE, even if it is  a  non-empty  directory  (super-user
      only; this works only if your system supports ‘unlink’ for 
          nonempty directories)
```

I don't think mingw supports `su root` or anything like it so using `rm -d` is unavailable.

Have you tried `rm -rf /full/path/to/dir` or (if empty) `rmdir /full/path/to/dir` ?

Comment: @tnorthcutt mingw does not support changes through chmod. The developers expect you to [maintain permissions via Windows](http://old.nabble.com/chmod-broken--td27652950.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mingw but on "real" *nix systems you need write access to the parent dir.  You don't specify the permissions of "dir" or it's parent directory but I assume that is the problem here as well.

Comment: For me, the permissions of the parent directory are drwxr-xr-x. I tried chmod 775 on the parent directory (which should result in drwxrwxr-x), but running ls -l again shows that the permissions did not change. If I run the chmod with the verbose flag, it claims that permissions were changed, but again, running ls -l shows that they were not.

Comment: FYI On my machine I have full permissions in Windows for this folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems like you're trying to 'rm' a directory ("dir"). "rmdir" would rather do the trick.

Otherwise, other things that come to mind:

1. Can you remove the file from windows explorer or a dos prompt? If yes, then it could be a mingw bug.
2. If the file is marked as "read-only" then you can't rm it.